# docker swarm - unable to connect to nginx container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have setup Docker swarm on single node and have created a container on it running nginx server but i am unable to connect to nginx server on specified port. Also, i am not able to attach to container. Any help is much appreciated.

```
[user@hostname yum.repos.d]$ sudo docker swarm init
[user@hostname yum.repos.d]$ sudo docker info | grep -i "swarm: active"
Swarm: active
[user@hostname yum.repos.d]$
[user@hostname yum.repos.d]$ sudo docker node ls
ID                           HOSTNAME                      STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx *            hostname.server.com           Ready   Active        Leader
[user@hostname yum.repos.d]$ sudo docker service create --name web --publish 8080:80 nginx
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo docker ps -a
[sudo] password for user: 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
xxxxxxxxxxx        nginx@sha256:ccdb5fdf47709493f9fc5af32478c0d86b3cbee0c306e3f04a0d3e640a50ea2d   "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    80/tcp              web.1.
[user@hostname ~]$ elinks http://localhost:8080 //says request sent but  no response received.
```

Above elinks command is unable to connect to url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works!!

```
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo docker service ps web
ID                  NAME                IMAGE               NODE                           DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE           ERROR               PORTS
xxxxxxxxxxxx        web.1               httpd:latest        hostname.myserver.com   Running             Running 3 minutes ago                       
[user@hostname ~]$ 
[user@hostname ~]$ elinks http://hostname.mylabserver.com:80
```

This works and connects to nginx running on port 80.

Thanks!!